# copy activity fail in azure data factory column delimiter issue?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a source csv file which i am loading to sql db using copy activity. In the 45th row i have a cell with this kind of data with unwanted characters.

Atualmente, as solicitaÃ§Ãµes de faturamento manual de serviÃ§os de mobilidade de clientes da RegiÃ£o

I tried loading the file. Its throwing error at row 45 that it has more column count than expected. I tried removing unwanted characters from this text. Then the copy actvty got executed. In source my delimiter is set as , by default. How can I handle this situation. Source csv file is in UTF8 format. in sql db i have set every column to varchar(max).

Comment: I reproduced this and got same error when the above row is not quoted. when it is quoted inside(" or '), I got the desired result as follows. https://i.imgur.com/x0dOOjD.png

Comment: i didnt get you. what you did in copy activity?

Comment: I didn't do anything in copy activity, just used double quotes(") https://i.imgur.com/T3elquT.png in the source csv file and imported both schemas of it in copy activity and able to get the output like above.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got the same error when I had the same data in my 3rd row without any double quotes for the data.

[image]

If you want to use the default delimiter(,), then use **double quotes(`"`)** over rows.

[image]

**Target data after copy activity:**

[image]